# Changing the case of JavaScript object keys

Tags: javascript

I have following object.

```
var obj = [{
  Address1: "dd",
  Address2: "qww",
  BankAccNo: "44",
  BankBranchCode: "44",
  BloodGrp: "A+"
},
{
  Address1: "dd",
  Address2: "qww",
  BankAccNo: "44",
  BankBranchCode: "44",
  BloodGrp: "A+"
}];
```

How can I make all of the keys uppercase?

I want to be able to access values like this : - `obj[0].ADDRESS1`

Comment: Why not just access them as they are?

Comment: @nnnnnn maybe because of consistency with some DB name fields, just guessing

Comment: Yes...I am matching this keys with values stored in DB, which are in Uppercase.!

Comment: if your js object has hierarchal structure and you want to capitalize only a specific object, https://jsfiddle.net/72q0ed6z/7/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
obj = obj.map( function( item ){
    for(var key in item){
        var upper = key.toUpperCase();
        // check if it already wasn't uppercase
        if( upper !== key ){ 
            item[ upper ] = item[key];
            delete item[key];
        }
    }
    return item;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/07xortqy/

Comment: This won't work if the key is already upper case. And I'm not sure how it will work on every browser because you change an object while looping on it with a `for in`

Comment: @SebastienC. thanks, added a safeguard for existing uppercase keys.

Answer (score 6):

1. Loop over all the properties in the object (with `for in`)
2. Use `.toUpperCase()` to get the uppercase version of the property name
3. Copy the value from the original property to the uppercase version
4. `delete` the original property

Comment: you complete pawel's answer nicely

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for a solution working with objects, arrays, and nested objects or arrays:

```js
// rename function depending on your needs
const capitalizeKeys = (obj) => {
  const isObject = o => Object.prototype.toString.apply(o) === '[object Object]'
  const isArray = o => Object.prototype.toString.apply(o) === '[object Array]'
  
  let transformedObj = isArray(obj) ? [] : {}
  
  for (let key in obj) {
    // replace the following with any transform function
    const transformedKey = key.replace(/^\w/, (c, _) => c.toUpperCase())

    if (isObject(obj[key]) || isArray(obj[key])) {
      transformedObj[transformedKey] = capitalizeKeys(obj[key])
    } else {
      transformedObj[transformedKey] = obj[key]
    }
  }
  return transformedObj
}

const t = {
  test1: 'hello',
  test2: {
    aa: 0,
    bb: '1',
    cc: [ 3, '4', 'world']
  },
  test3: [{
      aa: 5,
      bb: '6'
    }, {
      cc: [ 'hello', 'world', 7 ]
    }
  ]
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(capitalizeKeys(t)))
```

(this function is to be adapted since I only had to capitalize the first letter, and there is no need for the helper functions to be nested)

Comment: This looks what I want.

Comment: Absolutely universal solution 

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(obj, function(i, parent) {
  $.each(parent, function(key, record) {
    parent[ key.toUpperCase() ] = record[key]; //rename key
    delete parent[key]; //delete old key
  });
});
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer. Just code lines do not constitute a good answer.

Comment: first iterate array then iterate keys, inside second loop rename key and delete old one.

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = [
{ Address1: "dd",Address2: 'qww',BankAccNo: 44,BankBranchCode: 44,BloodGrp: 'A+' },
{ Address1: "dd",Address2: 'qww',BankAccNo: 44,BankBranchCode: 44,BloodGrp: 'A+' }
];

const uppercaseKeys = (elem) => {
  let newObject = {}

  Object.keys(elem).reduce( (acc, key, allKeys) => {
    acc[key.toUpperCase()] = elem[key]
    delete elem[key]
    return acc
  }, elem)

  return newObject
}

obj.forEach( o => uppercaseKeys )
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now also use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) in combination with [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) - have a look at the [Object transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Object_transformations) section.

```
const obj2 = obj1.map(item => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(item).map(([key, val]) => [
  key.toUpperCase(),
  val
])));
```

I've detailed the steps below:

```
// Iterate through each item in array
const obj2 = obj1.map(item => {
  // Object.entries() method returns array of object's own enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs, 
  // in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop
  const entries = Object.entries(item);

  // Convert keys to uppercase
  const uppercaseEntries = entries.map(([key, val]) => [
    key.toUpperCase(),
    val
  ]);

  // Object.fromEntries() method transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object.
  return Object.fromEntries(uppercaseEntries);
});`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/buj5y32x/3/

Answer (score 0):

For wider support, you are better off using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
const obj2 = obj1.map(item =>
  Object.keys(item).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
    // accumulator is the new object we are creating
    accumulator[key.toUpperCase()] = item[key];
    return accumulator;
  }, {})
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qf81ezsy/

Comment: problem with this one is that the accumulator will not inherit the prototype of the original item, I faced this problem.

Answer (score -2):

You could just loop through them and add new entries?

```
for (index in obj) {
  for (key in obj[index]) { 
     obj[index][key.toUpperCase()] = obj[key]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `for..in` to iterate over arrays is frowned upon. And now you have both upper- an lower-case keys, which may or may not be what OP wanted.